# API response to be stored locally

Tags: php, wp-query

Is it possible to refactor the code so that the API response would be stored locally for one day, instead of retrieving the data from the API each time the page loads?

```
<?php
// Assume "$list_api->get_items()" connects to an API.
$list_items = $list_api->get_items();

if(!empty($list_items)) {
    foreach($list_items as $list_item) {
?>
    <div class="item-container">
        <h2><?php echo $list_item['title']; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $list_item['paragraph']; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can store it in a transient for a day.

```
<?php
$list_items = get_transient( 'my_list_items' );
if ( false === $list_items ) {
    // Assume "$list_api->get_items()" connects to an API.
    $list_items = $list_api->get_items();
    set_transient( 'my_list_items', $list_items, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
}

if(!empty($list_items)) {
    foreach($list_items as $list_item) {
?>
    <div class="item-container">
        <h2><?php echo $list_item['title']; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $list_item['paragraph']; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

### References

- [`get_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_transient/)
- [`set_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/)

Comment: Much easier than the way I usualy do it!, always saved in options with a hardcoded timer. I love this community.

Comment: Transients are essentially options with hardcoded timers. (Also, as I understand it, if you're using `memcached`, then transients automagically use `memcached` as well.)